# The difference between 'wish I will be' and 'wish to be'

Tags: meaning, complements, wish-preterite

For example:

> 1. I wish I will be an Engineer.
> 2. I wish to be an Engineer.

is there any difference between the two sentences?

Comment: Yes, the first isn't idiomatic.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your question seems to be too basic for this community.  If you are speakers of other languages learning English, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on English Language Learners.

Comment: You need to show your own research. What you understand from it and what you don't. Otherwise, your question will not be welcome. Don't forget. [search and research](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: @deadrat Uhuh, but why?!

Comment: @Araucaria The OP didn't ask why but whether.  In any case, I'm pretty sure Ranthony has driven him off.  (Verbs of possibility, speculation, hope, etc. need the aspect of uncertainty or noncertainty in the verb of the following clause.)

Comment: Hi A010010001, welcome to EL&U.

Comment: @Araucaria The OP doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Rathony  My guess would be they belong on both. Probably more so on ELL, but this question itself belongs here, it seems to me. It more questions really that belong on one or the other.

Comment: @Rathony yes i'll keep that in mind, thank you very much, i think i asked in the wrong place

Comment: Please don't take it personally. You will be welcome and upvoted at English Language and Learners. Please try to follow their guidelines. Good luck.

Comment: @Rathony no i don't, thank you so much. have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the verb *WISH* changes according to what type of Complement it takes. When the verb *WISH* is used with a finite content clause , the meaning is counterfactual. We do not expect the thing described in the subordinate clause to happen:

- I wish I was taller.
- I wish I was a millionaire.
- I wish I was Einstein.

Notice that when we use a full finite clause after *wish* the tense is backshifted. The examples above, for instance, use the past simple *was* even though they are talking about the present. Notice that we cannot usually use *will* in these clause, we need a past tense form.

When we use the verb *wish* as a near synonym of *want* or *hope*, then we cannot use a finite clause afterwards. We need to use an infinitival clause:

- I wish to leave.
- I wish to be an engineer.
- I wish to be left in peace.

The use of *wish* in this type of sentence is relatively rare when compared to its use in the sentences further above; the other uses are far more frequent. When they are used, these sentences using *wish* are often used as a form of request, as opposed to as just a description of our mental state. They are quite formal in register.

If we use the verb *wish* with a Direct and Indirect Object, we also present the thing that is wished for as an actual possibility:

- I wish you a merry Christmas.
- I wish you good luck.
- I wish them wealth and happiness.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would use the past subjunctive (or whatever you want to call it): *I wish I were taller*.

Comment: @Anonym Yes, that's quite right. anywhere you can use a modally backshifted preterite , you can also use the 'subjunctive' too :-)  (I've tried to keep it simple for the OP!)

Comment: Most authorities would consider it wrong if you didn't use subjunctive "were," rather that "was," which, although often heard, is considered substandard.

Comment: @StevenLittman They would be wrong, though. The best most expert writers in English have consistently used both. There's nothing in the study of the language to suggest that *were* is in any way "better" apart from bogus prejudice. It's also not the case that *most* grammar authorities would say so. It's a, thankfully small minority.

Comment: @Araucaria--Both the NY Times Style Manual and the Chicago Manual of Style say to use "I wish I were..."  A quick look on the Net shows surprisingly more support for your position than I expected there to be, and maybe it's old-fashioned, but I'm sticking to my guns here.  "I wish I was..." really grates on my nerves.  The CMOS calls it "colloquial."  I say, don't put it in your term paper.  Your professor just might agree with the Times, the CMOS, and me.